# dictionary value operations shortcut

Tags: python, shortcut, dictionary

I am wondering why arithmetic operations on dictionary values cannot be shortened with `=+` or `=-` as normal python variables can:

```
for item in myDict:
    myDict[item] =+ 1
```

doesn't seem to work, but instead I'm told to use:

```
for item in myDict:
    myDict[item] = myDict[item] + 1
```

It doesn't seem very Pythonic to me, but perhaps there is a great explanation for this convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the operators is `+=` and `-=`, not the other way around:

```
In [31]: my_dict  = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}

In [32]: for item in my_dict:
   ....:     my_dict[item] += 1
   ....:

In [33]: my_dict
Out[33]: {'key1': 2, 'key2': 3} # values have been incremented by one
```